# Altair Charts containing Encoding of Special Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, visualization, altair

I am trying to plot a chart from a [spreadsheet](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/xls/PET_CONS_PSUP_DC_NUS_MBBLPD_M.xls) with this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
crude_df = pd.read_excel(open('PET_CONS_PSUP_DC_NUS_MBBLPD_M.xls', 'rb'),
              sheet_name='Data 1',index_col=None, header=2)  

alt.Chart(crude_df.tail(100)).mark_circle().encode(
    x = 'Date',
    y = r'U\.S\. Product Supplied of Normal Butane (Thousand Barrels per Day)'
)
```

I got this part of the code from the [Altair Documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#encodings-with-special-characters)

```
y = r'U\.S\. Product Supplied of Normal Butane (Thousand Barrels per Day)'
```

This is to mitigate the Chart appearing with empty content problem due to presence of special characters in Encodings

But I still get Error.

```
ValueError: U\.S\. Product Supplied of Normal Butane (Thousand Barrels per Day) encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be inferred because it does not match any column in the data.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the dot (`.`) present in the name of the columns of your spreadsheet/dataframe and It seems that the escape (suggested by the [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#encodings-with-special-characters)) does not work in your case.

As a workaround, you can remove the dot with pandas [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) before using [`altair.Chart`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html).

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

crude_df  = pd.read_excel("PET_CONS_PSUP_DC_NUS_MBBLPD_M.xlsx", sheet_name="Data 1", header=2)

crude_df.columns = crude_df.columns.str.replace("\.", "", regex=True)

alt.Chart(crude_df.tail(100)).mark_circle().encode(
    x = 'Date',
    y = 'US Product Supplied of Normal Butane (Thousand Barrels per Day)'
)
```

##### # Output :

[image]